# Porque al insertar datos desde mi formulario me lanza el mismo codigo php que hice y no inserta los datos?

Tags: mysql, html5, php7

Por favor ayudenme no tengo la menor idea de porque sale eso, dias atras me funcionaba correctamente, pero desde que actualice mi editor de text Sublime Text 3 es que sale eso, nose si eso tenga algo que ver.

Sale esto al presionar el boton Registrar de mi formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este en mi codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label>Nombre</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Nombre"><br>
    <label>Apellido</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Apellido"><br>
    <label>Telefono</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Telefono"><br>
    <label>Email</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
    <label>Comentario</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Comentario"><br><br>

    <p><button type="submit">Registrar</button></p>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías compartir por favor el código para hacer el **insert** en la base de datos

Comment: Junior, ya lo han dicho en otra de tus publicaciones, Por favor ve a [ask], si bien tu imagen trae el codigo de tu *index.php*  no es el mejor modo de mostrarnos. Ve al enlace que se te esta proporcionando y edita la pregunta según corresponda... Y LO MAS IMPORTANTE: si estas abriendo un archivo php primero tienes que iniciar el servidor desde XAMPP y entrar desde localhost o 127.0.0.1... darle doble click no hace que tu pagina se abra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes poner a correr el servidor `apache`, porque ahí solo lo estás ejecutando desde la carpeta, la ruta debe ser similiar a esta:

http://localhost/Prueba/archivo.html

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Hola Daniel B. Alzate, pues el archivo donde se registra la info se llama index por eso coloque eso?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir por favor el código para revisar cuál es el problema?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/285278/137594

Comment: Debes poner a correr el servidor apache, porque ahí solo lo estás ejecutando desde la carpeta, la ruta debe ser similiar a esta:

http://localhost/Prueba/archivo.php

Comment: Acabo de realizar eso y me sale este error:  

Notice: Undefined index: Nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: Apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\index.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: Telefono in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: Comentario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\index.php on line 12

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo *html* o *php* donde tienes el código del formulario?

Comment: Es un archivo html puse esta ruta: http://localhost/Prueba/index.html, salio el formulario registre datos, supuestamente fue exitoso pero voy a la base de datos y no los registro :c

Comment: Muestrame la tabla de tu base de datos, o genera otra pregunta con el error y me la compartes yo te ayudo.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/285284/137594