# Inserto datos en mi formulario, supuestamente el registro fue exitoso, pero cuando voy a verificar en mi base de datos no inserto los datos

Tags: phpmyadmin

Esta es la tabla que estoy usando y en  la que deberia registrarse los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask], de paso checar el [tour], por favor en la medida de lo posible agrega el código del form y de la alta, pues de otro modo no podemos hacer mucho. Saludos

Comment: ¿Por favor puedes mostrar el error que te muestra al momento de registrar un usuario para saber específicamente dónde está fallando?

Comment: Ese es el problema no me lanza ningun error.

Comment: Bienvenido Junior... **supuestamente**???  Como te diste cuenta? sale algún error? si es asi ¿que error sale?, Por favor, danos mas información para que podamos ayudarte... date una vuelta por [ask] para mas información...

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder, ya resolví el error.

Comment: Gracias @DanielB.Alzate por tu tiempo también

Comment: Excelente amigo, recuerda aceptar mi respuesta y ayudar a crecer a la comunidad. ¡Feliz decodificación!

Comment: Tienes razón Aprendiz, espero haya sido de ayuda mi respuesta, y si @Junior lo considera podrá optar por dar o no como aceptada la pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya había encontrado el error amigo, de esta manera es más optima, te recomiendo que pongas todo este código en `index.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "datos";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
  $apellido = $_POST['Apellido'];
  $telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
  $email = $_POST['Email'];
  $comentario = $_POST['Comentario'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,Email,Comentario) VALUES 
  ('$nombre','$apellido','$telefono','$email','$comentario')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Podrias poner cual fue su error ??? o por que seria este el metodo mas optimo???  ve a [answer] para mas informacion

Comment: Claro que si  Victor, el problema era que no estaba realizando bien la conexión a la base de datos, el código es más optimo porque el anterior no tenía los condicionales para validar si la respuesta por parte del servidor era exitosa. Por tal motivo no se encontraban errores al momento de realizar el **insert**. Además no se tenía respuesta del servidor si la conexión a la base de datos no era exitosa.

Comment: El pequeño detalle era que no ejecutaba la consulta "mysqli_query($conn,$sql)" solo me faltaba eso para que insertara los datos correctamente. Gracias nuevamente  @DanielB.Alzate